# PyScripter can`t import PyQt4.uic.Loader

Tags: python, pyqt, pyscripter

I import uic and QtGui from PyQt4 and I can`t compile my project because I have this message:[image]

I already have `__init__.py` file in uic\Loader, how to fix this problem?

---

### Update

I think PyScripter can`t see folder 'Loader' in uic. Why?
[image]

Comment: From a Python terminal, are you able to `import PyQt4.uic.Loader`?

Comment: Yes, but Pyscripter can`t see 'Loader' and i don`t know why.

Comment: I've added the [tag:pyscripter] tag to your question. Hopefully someone who watches that tag will know the answer!

Comment: @IgorAchmiz. Maybe you should use the [PyScripter Support Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/pyscripter) for questions like this.